# How do I use andengine with maven?

Tags: android, maven, andengine

I downloaded the source using

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/andengine/ andengine
```

And I'd like to know what the next step is to use andengine with maven.

Answer (score 0):

You should build the andengine first to create a jar file to be used as a dependency in your project. It seems andengine is using ant to build the project so that should work.
(You could also put andengine in its own maven module, use the ant mojos from maven to execute the build and put the jar in the local repository. But there will be new version and that may turn into migration work, I would split this task into andegnine and your project).

From there you can use the groupId/artifactId you chose above (to store the .jar in your local repo if there is no repository proxy in place) in your project.

Comment: Well, sure in theory.. But did you tried this yourself ? Can you explain it step-by-step ? (for example : how to create a jar file of Andengine ?)

Comment: you need to clone the sources from https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine.git
then use ant and (http://ant.apache.org) the build.xml to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting AndEngine from the wrong place, the project now lives on GitHub: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine
The Google Code repository is now probably very old and buggy!

On getting it from GitHub, see [this thread](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/use-andengine-as-a-android-library-project-not-as-a-jar-t6142.html).

Comment: I think it's mainly because the original question is quite old... However, this does not answer the question (which is about maven)

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that the question is so ancient. I am well aware that it does not really answer the question (I don't really care about the bounty), but I feel it's necessary to strongly discourage you from using the old version. It is buggy, not supported and undocumented. Not that the version on GitHub is documented, but at least the questions on SO and AndEngine forum will be relevant to the problems you may encounter. If the question is maven-specific, I think you should have posted a new question. This is very confusing and will lead people to give advice that won't be useful to you.